# Saving model record not working (Spine)

Tags: javascript, spine.js

I'm having problems saving a model record created from
the data of a form. Getting the data from the form using
`<Model>.fromForm(form)` works, as it includes all values.
However, when I'm saving the record it only saves the
cid of the record, nothing else.

This is what the record looks like when logging it:

`cid: "c-0"

email: "something"

password: "something"

password2: "something"

username: "something"

__proto__: ctor`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is an AJAX call made to the server? If so, are you sure it isn't a problem with the server?

Answer (score 2):

Are you configuring all the attributes of the model properly? You need to make sure to tell Spine what the model's attributes are like so:

```
class App.User extends Spine.Model
  @configure 'User', 'account_email', 'default_forwarding_address', 'forwarding_addresses'
```

I've run into issues where Spine doesn't "save" an attribute just because I forgot to configure it properly. Let me know if that helps!

Comment: Yes, naturally. The configuration looks like this:    

`var User = Spine.Model.sub();  
User.configure('User', ['email','username','password','password2']);  
User.extend(Spine.Model.Ajax);`    

And then the form inputs have the corresponding names, otherwise
I wouldn't be able to get the data at all.

Comment: I would say that @fholgado probably has the right answer.  Try taking your attributes out of the array brackets, I think that should do it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not using JavaScript myself, but try using `@setup` instead of `@configure`

The [Spince.js docs](http://spinejs.com/api/models) say:

> `@setup(name, [attributes...])`
>
> Alternative method for creating a new model class. This is a JavaScript compatibility feature, and shouldn't be used in CoffeeScript.
>
> `var User = Model.setup("User", ["first_name", "last_name"])`